# Servlet containers and classpath

Tags: java, servlets, jakarta-ee

To what is the class path of a Servlet container set?

As per my understanding there are three components involved. The JAR files in the `lib` directory of the Servlet container and then the classes in the `WEB-INF/classes` and JAR files in the `WEB-INF/lib` directory. The classes in `lib` directory of the Servlet container are added to the system classpath and the dynamic classpath includes the JAR files in the `lib` directory and classes in the `classes` directory.

To what is the dynamic classpath set? Does the dynamic classpath point to all the directories under `WEB-INF` or includes all the individual classes and JAR files in `WEB-INF/lib` and `WEB-INF/classes` or just points to the two directories `WEB-INF/classes` and `WEB-INF/lib`? Say I have a directory called `foo` in `WEB-INF` containing `bar.properties`. Now is `bar.properties` also in the class path?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The "dynamic" classpath will list `WEB-INF/classes` and each JAR file under `WEB-INF/lib` as a separate entry. Other folders under `WEB-INF` are *not* included.

In your example, `bar.properties` will not be on the classpath. Move it to `WEB-INF/classes`, or put it inside a JAR file under `WEB-INF/lib`.

What's in the rest of the classpath depends on your servlet container. It is implementation-specific, but most containers have two other places to put classes. One is a directory that is visible to the container, but not the applications, and the other is visible to the container and all of the applications. Since the second classloader is visible to all of the applications, static members of those classes can be used to share information between applications.

Comment: If other folders under WEB-INF lib are included then should not the properties file be included in the class path?

Comment: Sorry, that was an important typo, i meant "NOT included"!

Answer (score 2):

In your example bar.properties would need to be under the classes directory to be in the classpath.