# Is WEB-INF in the CLASSPATH?

Tags: java, classpath, web-inf

Is the `WEB-INF` folder in the `CLASSPATH` of a Java Web application?

Comment: This question seems to ask a similar thing: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/305285/servlet-containers-and-class-path

Answer (score 77, accepted):

I'm assuming you're referring to the `/WEB-INF` *directory* in the root of the web application folder structure.

No, it's not in the classpath.

`/WEB-INF/classes` is on the classpath though, and so are the JAR files in `/WEB-INF/lib`.

Comment: If /WEB-INF is not on the classpath, then why are the official 'deployment descriptor files' , such as web.xml , in that folder?  Do they still get loaded somehow even if they are supposedly not on the classpath?

Answer (score 12):

Additionally files in WEB-INF are protected against being requested by the web-container, i.e. they are invisible to the outside world.

Comment: Unless you forward the request (although BEA had a broken implementation of this many years ago).

Comment: You can almost always circumvent protection.