# Could not resolve Spring property placeholder

Tags: spring

I have my config:

```
<context:property-placeholder location="classpath:idm.properties" />

<bean id="idmPropertyHolder" class="fi.utu.resurssitilaus.idm.IdmPropertyHolder">
   <property name="url" value="${idm.url}" /> 
    <property name="user" value="${idm.user}" />
    <property name="password" value="${idm.password}" />
    <property name="proxyHost" value="${http.proxyHost}" />
    <property name="proxyPort" value="${http.proxyPort}" />
</bean>
```

I get the error

```
    SEVERE: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
    org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Invalid bean definition with name 'idmPropertyHolder' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/idm-config.xml]: Could not resolve placeholder 'idm.url'
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer.processProperties(PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer.java:272)
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyResourceConfigurer.postProcessBeanFactory(PropertyResourceConfigurer.java:75)
            at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:640)
            at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:615)
            at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:405)
            at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.createWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:276)
            at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:197)
            at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:47)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:3934)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4429)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:791)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:771)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:526)
            at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor(HostConfig.java:630)
            at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:514)
            at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.check(HostConfig.java:1288)
            at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
            at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
            at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
            at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:297)
            at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:836)
            at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:761)
            at org.apache.catalina.manager.ManagerServlet.check(ManagerServlet.java:1473)
            at org.apache.catalina.manager.ManagerServlet.deploy(ManagerServlet.java:824)
            at org.apache.catalina.manager.ManagerServlet.doGet(ManagerServlet.java:350)
            at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:617)
            at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
            at org.netbeans.modules.web.monitor.server.MonitorFilter.doFilter(MonitorFilter.java:196)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
            at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:525)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:128)
            at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
            at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:293)
            at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:849)
            at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:583)
            at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:454)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
    24.1.2011 9:19:05 org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
    INFO: Closing Spring root WebApplicationContext
    24.1.2011 9:19:05 org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
    INFO: Shutting down log4j
```

I know this could be missing properties file, but I have it in my classpath just right. What is missing?

My web.xml:

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>
      /WEB-INF/base-config.xml
      /WEB-INF/idm-config.xml
      /WEB-INF/ldap-config.xml
      /WEB-INF/sec-config.xml

    </param-value>
  </context-param>

  <!-- Reads request input using UTF-8 encoding -->
  <filter>
    <filter-name>characterEncodingFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter</filter-class>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>encoding</param-name>
      <param-value>UTF-8</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>forceEncoding</param-name>
      <param-value>true</param-value>
    </init-param>
  </filter>


  <filter>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
  </filter>

  <filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>characterEncodingFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
  </filter-mapping>


  <filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
  </filter-mapping>

  <listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.util.Log4jConfigListener</listener-class>
  </listener>


  <listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
  </listener>

  <listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.security.web.session.HttpSessionEventPublisher</listener-class>
  </listener>

  <!-- Handles all requests into the application -->
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
      <param-value>
        /WEB-INF/app-config.xml

      </param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>

  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>tiles</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.apache.tiles.web.startup.TilesServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>
        org.apache.tiles.impl.BasicTilesContainer.DEFINITIONS_CONFIG
      </param-name>
      <param-value>
        /WEB-INF/tiles-config.xml
      </param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>2</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>

  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.html</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>

  <session-config>
    <session-timeout>
      30
    </session-timeout>
  </session-config>

  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>redirect.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

Answer (score 105):

You may have more than one `org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer` in your application. Try setting a breakpoint on the `setLocations` method of the superclass and see if it's called more than once at application startup. If there is more than one `org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer`, you might need to look at configuring the `ignoreUnresolvablePlaceholders` property so that your application will start up cleanly.

Comment: I imported one application context from another one and each of them had it's own property place holder. Took me hours trying to figure it out (I had the same exception going on) and setting ignoreUnresolvablePlaceholders to true in the top app context did the trick. Thank you for writing this answer!

Comment: Same problem here only in my case I had one ppc in the xml and was apparently creating another by using the @PropertySource annotation elsewhere.  i got rid of the annotation and passed both props files to the ppc bean in the xml and viola.  thanks for the tip.

Comment: So simple, but so powerfull solution for resolve all problems with placeholder configs!

Comment: I had same problem but ignoreUnresolvablePlaceholders  solution doesn't resolve mine. Yes, I had one more place holder configurer, but it was at my server configuration and that still prevent reading config file. I removed that place holder configurer from server configuration and all work fine. Thanks for hint.

Answer (score 16):

Your property file location is `classpath:idm.properties`

This is rather unusual, it means that `idm.properties` must be located either at the top level of `WEB-INF/classes` or at the top-level of one of the jars inside `WEB-INF/lib`. Usually it's good practice to either use a dedicated folder for properties or keep them close to the context files that use them.

So my suggestion is this: Is your properties file perhaps next to your context file? If so, it's not on the classpath (see this question: [Is WEB-INF in the CLASSPATH?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/793917/is-web-inf-in-the-classpath)).

The `classpath:` prefix maps to a [`ClassPathResource`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/resources.html#resources-implementations-classpathresource), but you probably need a [`ServletContextResource`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/resources.html#resources-implementations-servletcontextresource), and you'll get that from a [`WebApplicationContext`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/index.html?org/springframework/web/context/WebApplicationContext.html) using the syntax without prefix:

```
<context:property-placeholder location="idm.properties" />
```

**Reference:**

- [The `ResourceLoader`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/resources.html#resources-resourceloader)
  (describes how different `ApplicationContext` types handle resources without prefix)
- [The `PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer`
  mechanism](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-factory-placeholderconfigurer)
  (describes the `<context:property-placeholder>` mechanism)

Comment: In the Spring petclinic example they put properties in src/main/resources and then reference them via classpath:app.properties.

Answer (score 11):

It's definitely not a problem with propeties file not being found, since in that case another exception is thrown.

Make sure that you actually have a value with key `idm.url` in your `idm.properties`.

Comment: I had copy-pasted the VM options from my startup script so they were all prepended with "-D". It hadn't occurred to me to check something this obvious... Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I still believe its to do with the props file not being located by spring. Do a quick test by passing the params as jvm params. i.e **-Didm.url=....**

Comment: I'm not familiar with jvm params

Comment: @mjgirl it's not that hard: `-Dkey=value` means setting the System Property "key" to "value"

Comment: Do yo mean I write that to properties file

Comment: @mjgirl let us say u have a class called "A" with main method in it. you can pass idm.url to "A" like this "java -Didm.url=http://www.abc.com A"

Answer (score 3):

make sure your properties file exist in classpath directory but not in sub folder of your classpath directory. if it is exist in sub folder then write as below classpath:subfolder/idm.properties

Answer (score 0):

the following property must be added in the gradle.build file

```
processResources {
    filesMatching("**/*.properties") {
        expand project.properties
    }
}
```

Additionally, if working with Intellij, the project must be re-imported.

Answer (score -7):

Ensure 'idm.url' is set in property file and the property file is loaded