# PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer does not find property file on disk

Tags: spring, osgi, blueprint

I am trying to move a working spring WAR to OSGI environment (in glassfish 3.1 and blueprint, spring 3.0.5).
The application loads properties file from disk, like this:

```
<bean id="myProperties" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
    <property name="location" value="${my_conf}/my.properties"/>
    <property name="systemPropertiesModeName" value="SYSTEM_PROPERTIES_MODE_OVERRIDE"/>
</bean>
```

I see in debugger that `${my_conf}/my.properties` is translated to the existing path (c:\conf\my.properties)

I use the property `jms.url` defined in `my.properties` in the next bean declaration

```
<amq:broker useJmx="false" persistent="false" brokerName="embeddedbroker">
    <amq:transportConnectors>
        <amq:transportConnector uri="tcp://${jms.url}"/>
        <amq:transportConnector uri="vm://embeddedbroker" />
    </amq:transportConnectors>
</amq:broker>
```

And in deployment I get an exception `"Could not resolve placeholder ${jms.url}"`

Why it fails? Is there another way to load properties from file on disk?

thank you

Comment: possible duplicate [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4779572/could-not-resolve-placeholder-problem). The one you see in debugger might be loaded by another bean in another applicationContext.xml

Comment: Thanks. I tried to set a location path to non-existing file, and did not get an exception. I tried to set a hard-coded path to the properties file, and nothing changed. Remember that it worked in non-osgi war

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It isn't a solution, but an explanation of my problem.
The problem is related to this [bug in spring 3 and osgi](https://jira.springsource.org/browse/SPR-6592).

I had to open spring logs to debug level to understand it.

Answer (score 0):

Since its an OSGI environment, you will need spring-osgi-core jar added to your application. Take a look at this [link](http://www.consulting-notes.com/2010/08/spring-osgi-compendium-example.html) to configure property-placeholder for OSGI framework.

Comment: Thank you. I thought I do not have to use osgix:cm-properties, according to this post: [osgi-spring-config](http://tech-tauk.blogspot.com/2009/12/osgi-spring-configuration-admin-dynamic.html). Am I wrong?

Comment: if you do not use spring-osgi-core you won't be able to use osgix tags in your context.xml as the schemas for these is located in spring-osgi-core

Comment: I am not using osgix tags meanwhile, I am using only bean and amq. I am using spring-osgi-core jar and many other spring jars, but it does not help me to solve the described problem