# test and applicationContext

Tags: spring, jpa

i use latest release of spring, spring data, jpa, hibernate and h2.
i try to run test (only repository test).

but i get this error: Failed to load ApplicationContext

my test class

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@TransactionConfiguration(transactionManager = "transactionManager", defaultRollback = true)
@Transactional
@ContextConfiguration(
    locations = {"classpath:applicationContext-test.xml"})
public class UserDaoTest extends AbstractTransactionalJUnit4SpringContextTests {
...
}
```

my applicationContext-test.xml  file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:jpa="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa"
   xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xsi:schemaLocation="
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.2.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa/spring-jpa-1.0.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.2.xsd">

<context:property-placeholder location="classpath:/jdbc.properties"/>

<context:component-scan base-package="com.test.*" />

<bean id="entityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
        <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter" />
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
    <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory" />
</bean> 

<jpa:repositories base-package="com.test.va.repository"/>

<bean id="dataSource" class="com.jolbox.bonecp.BoneCPDataSource" destroy-method="close">
    <property name="driverClass" value="${jdbc.driverClass}"/>
    <property name="jdbcUrl" value="${jdbc.url}"/>
    <property name="username" value="${jdbc.username}"/>
    <property name="password" value="${jdbc.password}"/>
    <property name="idleConnectionTestPeriodInMinutes" value="${jdbc.idleConnectionTestPeriodInMinutes}"/>
    <property name="idleMaxAgeInSeconds" value="${jdbc.idleMaxAgeInSeconds}"/>
    <property name="maxConnectionsPerPartition" value="${jdbc.maxConnectionsPerPartition}"/>
    <property name="minConnectionsPerPartition" value="${jdbc.minConnectionsPerPartition}"/>
    <property name="partitionCount" value="${jdbc.partitionCount}"/>
    <property name="acquireIncrement" value="${jdbc.acquireIncrement}"/>
    <property name="statementsCacheSize" value="${jdbc.statementsCacheSize}"/>
    <property name="releaseHelperThreads" value="${jdbc.releaseHelperThreads}"/>
</bean>
```

so it's a config error.

Comment: Can you paste the exception stack trace too? Or the exact error you see.

Comment: Could not resolve placeholder for context:property-placeholder  i added  xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context" to this file

Comment: Looks like its not finding /jdbc.properties.  Is the file  present?  Can you remove / and try?  Or make sure that path of jdbc.properties relative to classpath is correct?

Comment: Also, take a look at this one:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4779572/could-not-resolve-spring-property-placeholder