# context:property-placeholder doesn't resolve references

Tags: spring, mybatis

I have next `applicationContext.xml` file on the root of classpath:

```
<context:annotation-config />

    <context:property-placeholder location="classpath:props/datasource.properties"  />

    <bean id="datasource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource"
        p:username="${jdbc.username}" 
        p:password="${jdbc.password}" 
        p:url="${jdbc.url}"
        p:driverClassName="${jdbc.driverclass}" 
        p:validationQuery="SELECT sysdate FROM dual" />

    <bean id="sqlSessionFactory" class="org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionFactoryBean"
        p:dataSource-ref="datasource" 
        p:mapperLocations="classpath:mappers/*-mapper.xml" />

    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="txManager" />
    <bean id="txManager"
        class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager"
        p:dataSource-ref="datasource" />

    <bean id="mappeScannerConfigurere" class="org.mybatis.spring.mapper.MapperScannerConfigurer"
        p:sqlSessionFactory-ref="sqlSessionFactory" 
        p:basePackage="com.mypackage" />
```

`props/datasource.properties` also exists on the root of classpath with such content:

```
jdbc.url=myjdbcurl
jdbc.driverclass=myClass
jdbc.username=myUserName
jdbc.password=myPassword
```

I have a spring managed test where I declare to use previously mentioned applicationContext.xml via next annotations:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations = {"classpath:applicationContext.xml"})
```

When I invoke test method i get next error from spring:

```
org.apache.commons.dbcp.SQLNestedException: Cannot load JDBC driver class '${jdbc.driverclass}'
```

As I understand sping didn't resolve reference to jdbc.driverclass. 
What have I done wrong?

PS: I'm using spring 3.2.3.RELEASE

**

### EDIT

**

Perhaps the problem may be in `MapperScannerConfigurer`. It is a `BeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessor` and as Javadoc says:

> Extension to the standard BeanFactoryPostProcessor SPI,
>   allowing for the registration of further bean definitions
>   **before** regular BeanFactoryPostProcessor detection kicks in

So `MapperScannerConfigurer` instantiates datasource object via sqlSessionFactory with `BeanFacoryPostProcessor`(which is responsible for `<context:property-placeholder/>`) have not been utilized. 
So my question transforms to how to reorder `BeanFacoryPostProcessor` from `<context:property-placeholder/>` and `BeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessor`(`MapperScannerConfigurer`)?

### Resolved

After a couple hours of investigation I found the solution:

---

As I said earlier `MapperScannerConfigurer` is a `BeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessor` which fires before `BeanFactoryPostProcessor` which is responsible for `<context:property-placeholder/>`. So, during the creation of MapperScannerConfigurer references to external properties will not be resolved. In this case we have to defer the creation of datasource to the time after `BeanFactoryPostProcessor`have been applied. We can do that in several ways:

- remove `p:sqlSessionFactory-ref="sqlSessionFactory"` from `MapperScannerConfigurer`. In this case datasource object will not be created before `MapperScannerConfigurer`, but after `BeanFactoryPostProcessor` which is responsible for `<context:property-placeholder/>`. If you have more than one sqlSessionFactory in applicationContext, than can be some troubles
- In versions of mybatis-spring module higher than 1.0.2 there is a possibility to set `sqlSessionFactoryBeanName` instead of `sqlSessionFactory`. It helps to resolve PropertyPlaceHolder issue with `BeanFactoryPostProcessor`. It is a recommended way to solve this issue described in mybatis-spring  [doc](http://mybatis.github.io/spring/mappers.html#MapperScannerConfigurer)

Comment: Is there any other `PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer` in your Spring context configuration? [see this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4779572/could-not-resolve-spring-property-placeholder)

Comment: definitely no, I checked it by setting breakpoint in setLoctions method: it is called only once

Comment: I would try with a leading `/` for the properties location: `location="classpath:/props/datasource.properties"`

Comment: i have the same issue,and i just remove the autoWire=“byName",and the properties file work.

Comment: @maks you ripper. I had encountered the same issue that as soon as I added `MapperScannerConfigurer` it would screw with my property placeholders. When looking at the code I found that it implements `BeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessor` which is what lead me to believe it to be the cause and ultimately found your question. Answer your own question, man! This is the exact solution necessary :)

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue and came across this post but I was unable to resolve it the same way maks did. What ended up working for me was to set the ignoreUnresolvablePlaceholders property value to true.

```
<bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
    <property name="location">
        <value>classpath:database.properties</value>
    </property>
    <property name="ignoreUnresolvablePlaceholders" value="true"/>
</bean>
```

I am using Spring 3.2.3.RELEASE as well. I realize this post is over 4 months old but I figured someone might find it useful.

Answer (score 0):

**Short form:** What is the proper way to load an implementation of: BeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessor?

**Expanded form:** Is there a way to load BeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessor before any beans have been created. If you look at the javadoc:

> Extension to the standard {@link BeanFactoryPostProcessor} SPI, allowing for
>     the registration of further bean definitions *before* regular
>     BeanFactoryPostProcessor detection kicks in.

So it's meant to be loaded when bean definitions have been created but before any beans have been created. If we just create it as a regular bean in the application xml then it defeats the purpose of having this bean in the first place.