# spring cloud config client not injecting properties when MyBatis @MapperScan is present

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud, spring-mybatis

I have an spring-boot application with 3 `@Configuration` annotated classes: Application, DBScannerConfig and ElasticSearchConfiguration. My application also consumes configuration from a Spring Cloud Config Server.

The problem is that, when I try to annotate attributes with `@Value("${key}")`  inside the DBScannerConfig class, the properties don't get injected. However, if I use the `@Value("${key}")` annotation in the other two classes, the configuration works well.

I actually think it could be related to the `@MapperScan` annotation present in my DBScannerConfig configuration class.

What I would like to do is to either be able to retrieve properties or autowire spring's datasource in my `@MapperScan` annotated class, but I'm not being able to achieve such thing.

Does anyone faced this problem before? Here's the code:

**Application.java**

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableElasticsearchRepositories("org.myapp.elastic.repository")
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"org.myapp"})
public class Application extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Application.class);

//    @Autowired
//    DataSource dataSource;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);

    }

//Other Stuff for Spring Security
}
```

**DBScannerConfig.java**

```
@Configuration
@MapperScan("org.myapp.persistence.mapper")
public class DBScannerConfig{

    @Autowired
    DataSource dataSource;

    @Bean(name = "mySqlSessionFactory")
    public SqlSessionFactory mySqlSessionFactory() {
        SqlSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory = new SqlSessionFactoryBean();
        sessionFactory.setDataSource(dataSource);
        sessionFactory.setTypeAliasesPackage("org.myapp.persistence.entity");
        SqlSessionFactory sqlSessionFactory = null;
        try {
            sqlSessionFactory = sessionFactory.getObject();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            LOGGER.error("Error creating mySqlSessionFactory", e);
        }
        return sqlSessionFactory;
    }
}
```

If I uncomment the `@Autowired` datasource in Application.java I get a valid object. However, in the DBScannerConfig.java what I get is NULL.

I tried to autowire the Datasource object inside my Application.java class and then use it in the DBSCannerConfig.java with no luck. As soon as I add the `@MapperScan` annotation into the Application.java class it stops autowiring the spring datasource.

Comment: Little too generic, you should add some detail on how you define the bean. XML, JavaConf?

Comment: it's java-based configuration. let me edit the entry with some code snippets

Comment: Why do you need the transaction manager? Spring Boot already configures one. Inject the datasource into your method instead of the class, i.e. `mySqlSessionFactory(DataSource dataSource)`. Also don't call `getObject` but just return the `SqlSessionFactoryBean` that way spring will control your factory.

Comment: does it really matter? I mean, do you think changing that will solve the problem with the DataSource object not being autowired?

Comment: I realized something in this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17512596/contextproperty-placeholder-doesnt-resolve-references