# Weblogic deployment error

Tags: oracle, weblogic, weblogic-10.x, weblogic12c

I have deployed ear files in oracle weblogic server and i also configured datasource for that project. When i try to test it it is giving me this error.

"Message icon - Error weblogic.application.ModuleException: :org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException:Invalid bean definition with name 'userContext' defined in class path resource [voyager-seats-usercontext.xml]: Could not resolve placeholder 'IDM.USERNAME'
Message icon - Warning Errors were encountered while performing this operation."

I restarted and reconfigured this app still it is giving error.

Comment: Post your spring xml config file. This question is similar and may help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4779572/could-not-resolve-spring-property-placeholder