# cron issue with "Could not resolve placeholder"

Tags: java, spring, cron

I am working with cron in a STS web app I am developing and I am having a string format issue when trying to run the SpringMailSender on a cron timer. I am pulling the value for the cron from an external properties file and for some reason it does not seem to be liking it. Any ideas? Here is my code...

```
public class Timer {

     @Autowired
      private ApplicationContext ctx;

     @Autowired
        private SpringMailSender springMailSender;

    @Scheduled(cron="${ctx.getMessage('timer.time', null, null)}")
    public void timer()
    {
        System.out.println("timer() in Timer Class has been stepped into");
        try {
            springMailSender.sendMail();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        System.out.println("Method executed on every 2nd Monday of each month. Current time is :: "+ new Date());
    }

}
```

The info in the external properties file looks like this...

```
timer.time=0 0 8 ? 1/1 MON#2 *
```

the error I am getting is this...

```
"java.lang.IllegalStateException: Encountered invalid @Scheduled method 'timer': Could not resolve placeholder 'ctx.getMessage('timer.time', null, null)' in string value "${ctx.getMessage('timer.time', null, null)}"
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Could not resolve Spring property placeholder](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4779572/could-not-resolve-spring-property-placeholder)

Comment: I think you're looking for `#{...}`.

Comment: Why aren't you simlpy using a `PlaceHolderConfigurer` and `${timer.time}` instead of trying to abuse a `MessageSource` to obtain the property.

Comment: Dear Sotirios; well that sort of worked. It gave me a new error because now with the "#" symbol in it it seems to be trying to read {ctx.getMessage('timer.time', null, null)} as the cron expression and the error says "java.lang.IllegalStateException: Encountered invalid @Scheduled method 'timer': Cron expression must consist of 6 fields (found 3 in "#{ctx.getMessage('timer.time', null, null)}")"

Comment: @M. Deinum. I've never used that before. How would the code look?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `@Scheduled` annotation has support for using propert placeholders (i.e. `${...}`). For this to work you n eed to have a property placeholder configured.

```
<context:placholder-configurer location="path/to/your/external.properties" />
```

Then in your `@Scheduled` annotation you can simply reference the properties from the file.

```
@Scheduled(cron="${timer.time}")
```

That way you can also remove the dependency on the `ApplicationContext`.

Comment: do you mean Spring Property Placeholder Configurer? I'm not seeing anything for context:placeholder-configurer on Google.

Comment: What Deinum meant was to place this element context:placeholder-configurer in the bean definitions or context file (something like applicationContext.xml) where your Timer bean defined(since I dont see any annotation).