# Spring @PropertySource not reading environment variable

Tags: java, spring, properties

I think I've read all I could find on the topic, but cannot get the @PropertySource annotation to read an environment variable.

This works fine:

@PropertySource("file:C:\Code\java\myappname\configuration\myappname_config.properties")

But I do need to read the path from environment, so I have the **myappname_path** environment variable set up (I'm on Windows, with SpringBoot 1.5.4)

Either of those gets me "Could not resolve placeholder" exception:

@PropertySource("file:${**myappname_path**}\myappname_config.properties")
@PropertySource("file:${systemProperties['**myappname_path**']}\myappname_config.properties")

Thank you very much for help.

UPDATE: OK, that was my fault. Apparently, in this case the reboot was necessary to get the system property to take effect. 
So now this syntax works:
@PropertySource("file:${**myappname_path**}\myappname_config.properties")

This one does not, but it's not that important:
@PropertySource("file:${systemProperties['**myappname_path**']}\myappname_config.properties")

Thanks a lot for responses.

Comment: It should work. How and when did you define it? How are you running the app?

Comment: Check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4779572/could-not-resolve-spring-property-placeholder and in particular second answer

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a problem with how you have structured your project. To avoid issues like this I would use an IDE like IntelliJ if you are able to to build out you packages/modules/projects for you.

Generally, `.properties` files should live inside the `/resources` folder.

So change where you store that file and it should work. I will write your package directory in yaml format so you can follow:

```
src:
  main:
    java:
      packagename:
        ... package classes all in here ...
    resources:
      ... property files go here ...
```