# BeanInstantiationException - Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, dependency-injection

I've a weird problem of unable to instantiate a bean which is injected to another bean.

The `PropertiesUtil` is the bean in question. It's injected to the `LoginController` class as follows in my `sn-servlet.xml`

```
  <bean name="/Login.html" class="org.sn.auth.LoginController">
    <property name="dbUtil" ref="dbUtil"/>
    <property name="propertiesUtil" ref="propertiesUtil"/>
  </bean>
```

and my PropertiesUtil.java is

```
public class PropertiesUtil {

    private Properties properties;

    public PropertiesUtil() {
        properties = new Properties();
        try {            
                properties.load(ClassLoader.getSystemResourceAsStream(
                                    "/resources/messages.properties"));
        }
        catch (IOException ioException) {
            ioException.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

And the NullPointerException occurs at the line where I try to use the `properties` to `load` a resource. I'm really confused why it's null when I'm clearly instanting it in the previous line.

I've also tried injecting the `properties` instance as a `constructor-arg` and also as a `property` from the `sn-servlet.xml`, but all in vain.

Is there something like I'm not supposed to do any operations in a constructor when that bean is spring-injected to some other class?

Thanks for any ideas!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check out the javadoc for [`ClassLoader.getResourceAsStream()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/ClassLoader.html#getResourceAsStream%28java.lang.String%29).  It returns `null` if the resource cannot be found.  So it would seem that messages.properties cannot be found and the Properties.load() method will throw a `NullPointerException` when trying to read from a null `InputStream`.

Comment: oh! I've placed it under WEB-INF/resources. What's the proper way to access it then? The NPE made me think that `properties` was actually getting null!

Comment: Check out [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/793917/is-web-inf-in-the-classpath), WEB-INF is not on the classpath so the various `getResource..()` Methods will not be able to find it.  Move the file to `WEB-INF/classes/resources/messages.properties` and you should be able to pick it up.

Comment: dang! i just learnt a few days ago that `WEB-INF/classes` and `WEB-INF/lib` are in the classpath. Thanks a lot!